# Fedora12, yum can't find repositories

Tags: linux, fedora, package-management, yum

For some reasons I have to use old distro Fedora12, and yum in its default configuration is unable to locate URLs for packages.

```
% yum search gcc
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: fedora/
Please verify its path and try again
```

YUM repos configuration at */etc/yum.repos.d/fedora.repo* has the following:

```
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/$releasever/Everything/$basearch/os/
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-$releasever&arch=$basearch
```

This means that the above mentions site links are no longer valid, don't exist. Are there some mirrors still keeping packages for old distros? In this situation, what URL should I provide to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on fedora 20 with the same `/etc/yum.repos.d/fedora.repo` as you and yum can
find fedora 12 version files. Eg:

```
$ sudo yum --releasever=12 --installroot=/tmp/ list available '*gcc*'
(1/2): updates/12/x86_64/primary_db                     | 6.3 MB  00:54     
(2/2): fedora/12/x86_64/primary_db                      |  12 MB  01:49     
Determining fastest mirrors
 * fedora: ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de
 * updates: ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de
Available Packages
gcc.x86_64                     4.4.4-10.fc12               updates
```

What googling seems to suggest is that your certificates are not uptodate.
You should try a `yum clean all`, temporarily replace `https` with `http`
in the .repo file, and do `yum reinstall ca-certificates`.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any URLs that still work for Fedora 12.  You could try manually downloading a few packages if it's small, or you could try to mirror the old archive locally and use that as a yum repo, but Fedora 12 is well past its end of life, so there aren't live repos for it anymore.

To find individual packages, or the tree for where to download the repo from: https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/12/Fedora/i386/os/Packages/